# Render error. Exception: (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { class {

Tags: jestjs, koa, marko

when i start server with npm test the error above is shown but when i run server and test separately it works fine

detailed error message is :

Render error. Exception: /home/irisind/Akhil/myproj/components/app-head/index.marko:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { class {
                                                                    ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

```
at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
at Module._compile (module.js:617:28)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
```

console.error node_modules/koa/lib/application.js:185

Answer (score 0):

In order to use Marko within Jest you should use https://github.com/marko-js/jest since Jest does not support traditional require hooks.

Answer (score -1):

In order to use Marko on the server side you will need to register the require hook:

https://markojs.com/docs/installing/#require-marko-views